# observable first() and subscribe

Tags: rxjs

Is there a way to await for the first value returned from a subscribe call?

For example, in the following:

```
async getValue(...) {
  myObs$ = ...
  let val = await myObs$.pipe(first()).toPromise()
  myObs$.subscribe(val => {
    this.value = val
  })
  return val
}
```

The async function will return a Promise of val, but I also want to subscribe and get a data member value that will be updated whenever the observable myObs$ emits a new value.

My question: is there away to return a Promise without calling the line with the first() call and just wait for the first time I get the result in subscribe?

Comment: You can just switch the order and use `await myObs$.pipe(first()).toPromise()` after you subscribe.

Comment: Calling `toPromise` effects an implicit subscription to the observable upon which it's called.

Comment: I should say the code above works, but the question I have is related to the fact  that I am getting the value twice, once for the first() line and then within the subscribe. I am trying to determine if its possible to wait on the subscription and then return it, but ALSO continue to update the value for any future updates.

Comment: Why do you want to wait for the observable to emit a value? You could just call a function when you recieve a value in `subscribe` for the first time. This would be the reactive way to do it.

Comment: I need the value synchronously and also want to cache the value (and keep it updated) so I don't have to go to the server again. There only real issue is that I have to go to the server twice in the above code, and was hoping to avoid that extra call.

Answer (score 0):

There's no real reason here that this method needs to be async as the caller will have to await it or use .then() regardless. You could simply rewrite it as:

```js
getValue(...) {
  myObs$ = ...
  myObs$.subscribe(val => {
    this.value = val
  })
  return myObs$.pipe(first()).toPromise()
}
```

This will keep your internal subscription around and allow it to keep receiving values while the caller of `getValue` will receive a Promise of the first emitted value.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however, the code I wrote will wait for the value and return it synchronously, and also subscribe for future updates, but the first update will come in twice, and I was hoping to only get the first one once somehow.